# Swift3 webview isUserInteractionEnabled not working

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift3, uiwebview

My objective is to load a remote html, replace tags and show it in the webview. Everything is working fine, but isUserInteractionEnabled = true it's not working. I know this because I can't scroll down. I think this is about calling self.webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil) inside session.dataTask(). My question is: Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let url = "https://example.com"
       let requestURL = URL(string:url)
       var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)

       request.httpMethod = "GET"
       let session = URLSession.shared

       self.webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

       session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
           let html = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
           self.webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
       }.resume()

       // webView.loadRequest(request)
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
   }
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. I can scroll down but tapping in any link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should use `UIWebView`'s API to load the request, instead of `URLSession`:</strike>

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = "https://www.google.com"
    let requestURL = URL(string:url)
    let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

**Edit** I thought you were just trying to show that webpage. I believe in order to transform the `html` you downloaded using `URLSession` and then render it, you might need to try the `ascii` encoding instead of `uft8`.

You also should not have to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` on `UIWebView` since it is its default value (Check `storyboard/xib`, it should already be ticked when you drag an object of type `UIWebView`)

However be aware that loading a webpage that way will lead into other issues as separate resources like images/css/etc will not be downloaded, so the webpage might look "broken" after rendering